# MSSQL_CONNECT returns nothing - no error but no response either

Tags: php, sql-server, iis

I have MSSQL and an IIS7 server but would like to write a PHP website that can retrieve data from my database.

I have switched all my `mysql_` instances with `mssql_`, but it simply won't connect when I try:

```
$this->connection = mssql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
```

I have echo'd out the 3 pieces of data above and all are correct. I cannot echo anything after the line above, it completely kills it.

I have custom error reporting and have even tried taking it off, to no avail - just a blank page:

```
set_error_handler("customError");
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);
```

Can some one point me in the right direction for setting up IIS to be able to connect through `mssql_connect` please? I enjoy programming but server config is not my forte!

Here is the mssql block in my php.ini file located: C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3

```
[MSSQL]
; Allow or prevent persistent links.
mssql.allow_persistent = On

; Maximum number of persistent links.  -1 means no limit.
mssql.max_persistent = -1

; Maximum number of links (persistent+non persistent).  -1 means no limit.
mssql.max_links = -1

; Minimum error severity to display.
mssql.min_error_severity = 10

; Minimum message severity to display.
mssql.min_message_severity = 10

; Compatibility mode with old versions of PHP 3.0.
mssql.compatability_mode = Off

; Connect timeout
;mssql.connect_timeout = 5

; Query timeout
;mssql.timeout = 60

; Valid range 0 - 2147483647.  Default = 4096.
;mssql.textlimit = 4096

; Valid range 0 - 2147483647.  Default = 4096.
;mssql.textsize = 4096

; Limits the number of records in each batch.  0 = all records in one batch.
;mssql.batchsize = 0

; Specify how datetime and datetim4 columns are returned
; On => Returns data converted to SQL server settings
; Off => Returns values as YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss
;mssql.datetimeconvert = On

; Use NT authentication when connecting to the server
mssql.secure_connection = Off

; Specify max number of processes. -1 = library default
; msdlib defaults to 25
; FreeTDS defaults to 4096
;mssql.max_procs = -1

; Specify client character set.
; If empty or not set the client charset from freetds.comf is used
; This is only used when compiled with FreeTDS
;mssql.charset = "ISO-8859-1"
```

Here is my phpinfo(INFO_MODULES)

```
    bcmath
BCMath support  enabled

Directive   Local Value Master Value
bcmath.scale    0   0

calendar
Calendar support    enabled

cgi-fcgi
Directive   Local Value Master Value
cgi.check_shebang_line  1   1
cgi.discard_path    0   0
cgi.fix_pathinfo    1   1
cgi.force_redirect  0   0
cgi.nph 0   0
cgi.redirect_status_env no value    no value
cgi.rfc2616_headers 0   0
fastcgi.impersonate 1   1
fastcgi.logging 1   1

com_dotnet
COM support enabled
DCOM support    disabled
.Net support    enabled

Directive   Local Value Master Value
com.allow_dcom  0   0
com.autoregister_casesensitive  1   1
com.autoregister_typelib    0   0
com.autoregister_verbose    0   0
com.code_page   no value    no value
com.typelib_file    no value    no value

Core
PHP Version     5.3.6

Directive   Local Value Master Value
allow_call_time_pass_reference  Off Off
allow_url_fopen On  On
allow_url_include   Off Off
always_populate_raw_post_data   Off Off
arg_separator.input &   &
arg_separator.output    &   &
asp_tags    Off Off
auto_append_file    no value    no value
auto_globals_jit    On  On
auto_prepend_file   no value    no value
browscap    no value    no value
default_charset no value    no value
default_mimetype    text/html   text/html
define_syslog_variables Off Off
disable_classes no value    no value
disable_functions   no value    no value
display_errors  On  On
display_startup_errors  Off Off
doc_root    no value    no value
docref_ext  no value    no value
docref_root no value    no value
enable_dl   Off Off
error_append_string no value    no value
error_log   C:\Windows\temp\php53_errors.log    C:\Windows\temp\php53_errors.log
error_prepend_string    no value    no value
error_reporting 32767   32767
exit_on_timeout Off Off
expose_php  On  On
extension_dir   C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\ext\    C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\ext\
file_uploads    On  On
highlight.bg    #FFFFFF #FFFFFF
highlight.comment   #FF8000 #FF8000
highlight.default   #0000BB #0000BB
highlight.html  #000000 #000000
highlight.keyword   #007700 #007700
highlight.string    #DD0000 #DD0000
html_errors On  On
ignore_repeated_errors  Off Off
ignore_repeated_source  Off Off
ignore_user_abort   Off Off
implicit_flush  Off Off
include_path    .;C:\php\pear   .;C:\php\pear
log_errors  On  On
log_errors_max_len  1024    1024
magic_quotes_gpc    Off Off
magic_quotes_runtime    Off Off
magic_quotes_sybase Off Off
mail.add_x_header   On  On
mail.force_extra_parameters no value    no value
mail.log    no value    no value
max_execution_time  300 300
max_file_uploads    20  20
max_input_nesting_level 64  64
max_input_time  60  60
memory_limit    128M    128M
open_basedir    no value    no value
output_buffering    4096    4096
output_handler  no value    no value
post_max_size   8M  8M
precision   14  14
realpath_cache_size 16K 16K
realpath_cache_ttl  120 120
register_argc_argv  Off Off
register_globals    Off Off
register_long_arrays    Off Off
report_memleaks On  On
report_zend_debug   On  On
request_order   GP  GP
safe_mode   Off Off
safe_mode_exec_dir  no value    no value
safe_mode_gid   Off Off
safe_mode_include_dir   no value    no value
sendmail_from   no value    no value
sendmail_path   no value    no value
serialize_precision 17  17
short_open_tag  Off Off
SMTP    localhost   localhost
smtp_port   25  25
sql.safe_mode   Off Off
track_errors    On  On
unserialize_callback_func   no value    no value
upload_max_filesize 2M  2M
upload_tmp_dir  C:\Windows\temp C:\Windows\temp
user_dir    no value    no value
user_ini.cache_ttl  300 300
user_ini.filename   .user.ini   .user.ini
variables_order GPCS    GPCS
xmlrpc_error_number 0   0
xmlrpc_errors   Off Off
y2k_compliance  On  On
zend.enable_gc  On  On

ctype
ctype functions     enabled

curl
cURL support    enabled
cURL Information    7.21.2
Age     3
Features
AsynchDNS   Yes
Debug   No
GSS-Negotiate   No
IDN     No
IPv6    Yes
Largefile   Yes
NTLM    Yes
SPNEGO  No
SSL     Yes
SSPI    Yes
krb4    No
libz    Yes
CharConv    No
Protocols   dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, pop3, pop3s, rtsp, scp, sftp, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
Host    i386-pc-win32
SSL Version     OpenSSL/0.9.8r
ZLib Version    1.2.3
libSSH Version  libssh2/1.2.7

date
date/time support   enabled
"Olson" Timezone Database Version   2011.4
Timezone Database   internal
Default timezone    Europe/Minsk

Directive   Local Value Master Value
date.default_latitude   31.7667 31.7667
date.default_longitude  35.2333 35.2333
date.sunrise_zenith 90.583333   90.583333
date.sunset_zenith  90.583333   90.583333
date.timezone   Europe/Minsk    Europe/Minsk

dom
DOM/XML     enabled
DOM/XML API Version     20031129
libxml Version  2.7.7
HTML Support    enabled
XPath Support   enabled
XPointer Support    enabled
Schema Support  enabled
RelaxNG Support     enabled

ereg
Regex Library   Bundled library enabled

exif
EXIF Support    enabled
EXIF Version    1.4 $Id: exif.c 308362 2011-02-15 14:02:26Z pajoye $
Supported EXIF Version  0220
Supported filetypes     JPEG,TIFF

Directive   Local Value Master Value
exif.decode_jis_intel   JIS JIS
exif.decode_jis_motorola    JIS JIS
exif.decode_unicode_intel   UCS-2LE UCS-2LE
exif.decode_unicode_motorola    UCS-2BE UCS-2BE
exif.encode_jis no value    no value
exif.encode_unicode ISO-8859-15 ISO-8859-15

filter
Input Validation and Filtering  enabled
Revision    $Revision: 306939 $

Directive   Local Value Master Value
filter.default  unsafe_raw  unsafe_raw
filter.default_flags    no value    no value

ftp
FTP support     enabled

gd
GD Support  enabled
GD Version  bundled (2.0.34 compatible)
FreeType Support    enabled
FreeType Linkage    with freetype
FreeType Version    2.4.3
GIF Read Support    enabled
GIF Create Support  enabled
JPEG Support    enabled
libJPEG Version     6b
PNG Support     enabled
libPNG Version  1.2.44
WBMP Support    enabled
XBM Support     enabled

Directive   Local Value Master Value
gd.jpeg_ignore_warning  0   0

gettext
GetText Support     enabled

hash
hash support    enabled
Hashing Engines     md2 md4 md5 sha1 sha224 sha256 sha384 sha512 ripemd128 ripemd160 ripemd256 ripemd320 whirlpool tiger128,3 tiger160,3 tiger192,3 tiger128,4 tiger160,4 tiger192,4 snefru snefru256 gost adler32 crc32 crc32b salsa10 salsa20 haval128,3 haval160,3 haval192,3 haval224,3 haval256,3 haval128,4 haval160,4 haval192,4 haval224,4 haval256,4 haval128,5 haval160,5 haval192,5 haval224,5 haval256,5

iconv
iconv support   enabled
iconv implementation    "libiconv"
iconv library version   1.11

Directive   Local Value Master Value
iconv.input_encoding    ISO-8859-1  ISO-8859-1
iconv.internal_encoding ISO-8859-1  ISO-8859-1
iconv.output_encoding   ISO-8859-1  ISO-8859-1

imap
IMAP c-Client Version   2007e
SSL Support     enabled

json
json support    enabled
json version    1.2.1

libxml
libXML support  active
libXML Compiled Version     2.7.7
libXML Loaded Version   20707
libXML streams  enabled

mbstring
Multibyte Support   enabled
Multibyte string engine     libmbfl
HTTP input encoding translation     disabled

mbstring extension makes use of "streamable kanji code filter and converter", which is distributed under the GNU Lesser General Public License version 2.1.

Multibyte (japanese) regex support  enabled
Multibyte regex (oniguruma) version     4.7.1

Directive   Local Value Master Value
mbstring.detect_order   no value    no value
mbstring.encoding_translation   Off Off
mbstring.func_overload  0   0
mbstring.http_input pass    pass
mbstring.http_output    pass    pass
mbstring.http_output_conv_mimetypes ^(text/|application/xhtml\+xml) ^(text/|application/xhtml\+xml)
mbstring.internal_encoding  no value    no value
mbstring.language   neutral neutral
mbstring.strict_detection   Off Off
mbstring.substitute_character   no value    no value

mcrypt
mcrypt support  enabled
mcrypt_filter support   enabled
Version     2.5.8
Api No  20021217
Supported ciphers   cast-128 gost rijndael-128 twofish cast-256 loki97 rijndael-192 saferplus wake blowfish-compat des rijndael-256 serpent xtea blowfish enigma rc2 tripledes arcfour
Supported modes     cbc cfb ctr ecb ncfb nofb ofb stream

Directive   Local Value Master Value
mcrypt.algorithms_dir   no value    no value
mcrypt.modes_dir    no value    no value

mhash
MHASH support   Enabled
MHASH API Version   Emulated Support

mysql
MySQL Support   enabled
Active Persistent Links     0
Active Links    0
Client API version  mysqlnd 5.0.8-dev - 20102224 - $Revision: 308673 $

Directive   Local Value Master Value
mysql.allow_local_infile    On  On
mysql.allow_persistent  On  On
mysql.connect_timeout   60  60
mysql.default_host  no value    no value
mysql.default_password  no value    no value
mysql.default_port  no value    no value
mysql.default_socket    no value    no value
mysql.default_user  no value    no value
mysql.max_links Unlimited   Unlimited
mysql.max_persistent    Unlimited   Unlimited
mysql.trace_mode    Off Off

mysqli
MysqlI Support  enabled
Client API library version  mysqlnd 5.0.8-dev - 20102224 - $Revision: 308673 $
Active Persistent Links     0
Inactive Persistent Links   0
Active Links    0

Directive   Local Value Master Value
mysqli.allow_local_infile   On  On
mysqli.allow_persistent On  On
mysqli.default_host no value    no value
mysqli.default_port 3306    3306
mysqli.default_pw   no value    no value
mysqli.default_socket   no value    no value
mysqli.default_user no value    no value
mysqli.max_links    Unlimited   Unlimited
mysqli.max_persistent   Unlimited   Unlimited
mysqli.reconnect    Off Off

mysqlnd
mysqlnd enabled
Version     mysqlnd 5.0.8-dev - 20102224 - $Revision: 308673 $
Compression     supported
SSL     supported
Command buffer size     4096
Read buffer size    32768
Read timeout    31536000
Collecting statistics   Yes
Collecting memory statistics    No
Tracing     n/a

Client statistics   
bytes_sent  0
bytes_received  0
packets_sent    0
packets_received    0
protocol_overhead_in    0
protocol_overhead_out   0
bytes_received_ok_packet    0
bytes_received_eof_packet   0
bytes_received_rset_header_packet   0
bytes_received_rset_field_meta_packet   0
bytes_received_rset_row_packet  0
bytes_received_prepare_response_packet  0
bytes_received_change_user_packet   0
packets_sent_command    0
packets_received_ok     0
packets_received_eof    0
packets_received_rset_header    0
packets_received_rset_field_meta    0
packets_received_rset_row   0
packets_received_prepare_response   0
packets_received_change_user    0
result_set_queries  0
non_result_set_queries  0
no_index_used   0
bad_index_used  0
slow_queries    0
buffered_sets   0
unbuffered_sets     0
ps_buffered_sets    0
ps_unbuffered_sets  0
flushed_normal_sets     0
flushed_ps_sets     0
ps_prepared_never_executed  0
ps_prepared_once_executed   0
rows_fetched_from_server_normal     0
rows_fetched_from_server_ps     0
rows_buffered_from_client_normal    0
rows_buffered_from_client_ps    0
rows_fetched_from_client_normal_buffered    0
rows_fetched_from_client_normal_unbuffered  0
rows_fetched_from_client_ps_buffered    0
rows_fetched_from_client_ps_unbuffered  0
rows_fetched_from_client_ps_cursor  0
rows_affected_normal    0
rows_affected_ps    0
rows_skipped_normal     0
rows_skipped_ps     0
copy_on_write_saved     0
copy_on_write_performed     0
command_buffer_too_small    0
connect_success     0
connect_failure     0
connection_reused   0
reconnect   0
pconnect_success    0
active_connections  0
active_persistent_connections   0
explicit_close  0
implicit_close  0
disconnect_close    0
in_middle_of_command_close  0
explicit_free_result    0
implicit_free_result    0
explicit_stmt_close     0
implicit_stmt_close     0
mem_emalloc_count   0
mem_emalloc_amount  0
mem_ecalloc_count   0
mem_ecalloc_amount  0
mem_erealloc_count  0
mem_erealloc_amount     0
mem_efree_count     0
mem_efree_amount    0
mem_malloc_count    0
mem_malloc_amount   0
mem_calloc_count    0
mem_calloc_amount   0
mem_realloc_count   0
mem_realloc_amount  0
mem_free_count  0
mem_free_amount     0
mem_estrndup_count  0
mem_strndup_count   0
mem_estndup_count   0
mem_strdup_count    0
proto_text_fetched_null     0
proto_text_fetched_bit  0
proto_text_fetched_tinyint  0
proto_text_fetched_short    0
proto_text_fetched_int24    0
proto_text_fetched_int  0
proto_text_fetched_bigint   0
proto_text_fetched_decimal  0
proto_text_fetched_float    0
proto_text_fetched_double   0
proto_text_fetched_date     0
proto_text_fetched_year     0
proto_text_fetched_time     0
proto_text_fetched_datetime     0
proto_text_fetched_timestamp    0
proto_text_fetched_string   0
proto_text_fetched_blob     0
proto_text_fetched_enum     0
proto_text_fetched_set  0
proto_text_fetched_geometry     0
proto_text_fetched_other    0
proto_binary_fetched_null   0
proto_binary_fetched_bit    0
proto_binary_fetched_tinyint    0
proto_binary_fetched_short  0
proto_binary_fetched_int24  0
proto_binary_fetched_int    0
proto_binary_fetched_bigint     0
proto_binary_fetched_decimal    0
proto_binary_fetched_float  0
proto_binary_fetched_double     0
proto_binary_fetched_date   0
proto_binary_fetched_year   0
proto_binary_fetched_time   0
proto_binary_fetched_datetime   0
proto_binary_fetched_timestamp  0
proto_binary_fetched_string     0
proto_binary_fetched_blob   0
proto_binary_fetched_enum   0
proto_binary_fetched_set    0
proto_binary_fetched_geometry   0
proto_binary_fetched_other  0
init_command_executed_count     0
init_command_failed_count   0
com_quit    0
com_init_db     0
com_query   0
com_field_list  0
com_create_db   0
com_drop_db     0
com_refresh     0
com_shutdown    0
com_statistics  0
com_process_info    0
com_connect     0
com_process_kill    0
com_debug   0
com_ping    0
com_time    0
com_delayed_insert  0
com_change_user     0
com_binlog_dump     0
com_table_dump  0
com_connect_out     0
com_register_slave  0
com_stmt_prepare    0
com_stmt_execute    0
com_stmt_send_long_data     0
com_stmt_close  0
com_stmt_reset  0
com_stmt_set_option     0
com_stmt_fetch  0
com_deamon  0
bytes_received_real_data_normal     0
bytes_received_real_data_ps     0

odbc
ODBC Support    enabled
Active Persistent Links     0
Active Links    0
ODBC library    Win32

Directive   Local Value Master Value
odbc.allow_persistent   On  On
odbc.check_persistent   On  On
odbc.default_cursortype Static cursor   Static cursor
odbc.default_db no value    no value
odbc.default_pw no value    no value
odbc.default_user   no value    no value
odbc.defaultbinmode return as is    return as is
odbc.defaultlrl return up to 4096 bytes return up to 4096 bytes
odbc.max_links  Unlimited   Unlimited
odbc.max_persistent Unlimited   Unlimited

openssl
OpenSSL support     enabled
OpenSSL Library Version     OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
OpenSSL Header Version  OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011

pcre
PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) Support  enabled
PCRE Library Version    8.11 2010-12-10

Directive   Local Value Master Value
pcre.backtrack_limit    100000  100000
pcre.recursion_limit    100000  100000

PDO
PDO support enabled
PDO drivers     mysql, sqlite

pdo_mysql
PDO Driver for MySQL    enabled
Client API version  mysqlnd 5.0.8-dev - 20102224 - $Revision: 308673 $

pdo_sqlite
PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x   enabled
SQLite Library  3.7.4

Phar
Phar: PHP Archive support   enabled
Phar EXT version    2.0.1
Phar API version    1.1.1
SVN revision    $Revision: 307915 $
Phar-based phar archives    enabled
Tar-based phar archives     enabled
ZIP-based phar archives     enabled
gzip compression    enabled
bzip2 compression   disabled (install pecl/bz2)
OpenSSL support     enabled

Phar based on pear/PHP_Archive, original concept by Davey Shafik.
Phar fully realized by Gregory Beaver and Marcus Boerger.
Portions of tar implementation Copyright (c) 2003-2009 Tim Kientzle.

Directive   Local Value Master Value
phar.cache_list no value    no value
phar.readonly   On  On
phar.require_hash   On  On

Reflection
Reflection  enabled
Version     $Revision: 307971 $

session
Session Support     enabled
Registered save handlers    files user
Registered serializer handlers  php php_binary wddx

Directive   Local Value Master Value
session.auto_start  Off Off
session.bug_compat_42   Off Off
session.bug_compat_warn Off Off
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly Off Off
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_secure   Off Off
session.entropy_file    no value    no value
session.entropy_length  0   0
session.gc_divisor  1000    1000
session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440
session.gc_probability  1   1
session.hash_bits_per_character 5   5
session.hash_function   0   0
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    files   files
session.save_path   C:\Windows\temp C:\Windows\temp
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.use_cookies On  On
session.use_only_cookies    On  On
session.use_trans_sid   0   0

SimpleXML
Simplexml support   enabled
Revision    $Revision: 308262 $
Schema support  enabled

soap
Soap Client     enabled
Soap Server     enabled

Directive   Local Value Master Value
soap.wsdl_cache 1   1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir /tmp    /tmp
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled 1   1
soap.wsdl_cache_limit   5   5
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl 86400   86400

SPL
SPL support enabled
Interfaces  Countable, OuterIterator, RecursiveIterator, SeekableIterator, SplObserver, SplSubject
Classes     AppendIterator, ArrayIterator, ArrayObject, BadFunctionCallException, BadMethodCallException, CachingIterator, DirectoryIterator, DomainException, EmptyIterator, FilesystemIterator, FilterIterator, GlobIterator, InfiniteIterator, InvalidArgumentException, IteratorIterator, LengthException, LimitIterator, LogicException, MultipleIterator, NoRewindIterator, OutOfBoundsException, OutOfRangeException, OverflowException, ParentIterator, RangeException, RecursiveArrayIterator, RecursiveCachingIterator, RecursiveDirectoryIterator, RecursiveFilterIterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator, RecursiveRegexIterator, RecursiveTreeIterator, RegexIterator, RuntimeException, SplDoublyLinkedList, SplFileInfo, SplFileObject, SplFixedArray, SplHeap, SplMinHeap, SplMaxHeap, SplObjectStorage, SplPriorityQueue, SplQueue, SplStack, SplTempFileObject, UnderflowException, UnexpectedValueException

standard
Dynamic Library Support     enabled
Internal Sendmail Support for Windows   enabled

Directive   Local Value Master Value
assert.active   1   1
assert.bail 0   0
assert.callback no value    no value
assert.quiet_eval   0   0
assert.warning  1   1
auto_detect_line_endings    0   0
default_socket_timeout  60  60
from    no value    no value
safe_mode_allowed_env_vars  PHP_    PHP_
safe_mode_protected_env_vars    LD_LIBRARY_PATH LD_LIBRARY_PATH
url_rewriter.tags   a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry
user_agent  no value    no value

tidy
Tidy support    enabled
libTidy Release     25 March 2009
Extension Version   2.0 ($Id: tidy.c 306939 2011-01-01 02:19:59Z felipe $)

Directive   Local Value Master Value
tidy.clean_output   no value    no value
tidy.default_config no value    no value

tokenizer
Tokenizer Support   enabled

wddx
WDDX Support    enabled
WDDX Session Serializer     enabled

xml
XML Support     active
XML Namespace Support   active
libxml2 Version     2.7.7

xmlreader
XMLReader   enabled

xmlrpc
core library version    xmlrpc-epi v. 0.51
php extension version   0.51
author  Dan Libby
homepage    http://xmlrpc-epi.sourceforge.net
open sourced by     Epinions.com

xmlwriter
XMLWriter   enabled

zip
Zip     enabled
Extension Version   $Id: php_zip.c 308107 2011-02-07 16:20:16Z pajoye $
Zip version     1.9.1
Libzip version  0.9.0

zlib
ZLib Support    enabled
Stream Wrapper support  compress.zlib://
Stream Filter support   zlib.inflate, zlib.deflate
Compiled Version    1.2.5
Linked Version  1.2.5

Directive   Local Value Master Value
zlib.output_compression Off Off
zlib.output_compression_level   -1  -1
zlib.output_handler no value    no value

Additional Modules
Module Name

1
```

Comment: Have you checked that the mssql extension is enabled in your ini file?

Comment: As an aside, I suggest you look at the [newer sql server driver for php written by Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=20098). Lots of features will not work with the old driver. One example I noted is queries that use filtered indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with php_mssql.dll is it doesn't work on PHP 5.3!

You need to install SQLSRV which I found out on another forum. Use the Microsoft Web Installer to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP manual is the best place to look for information about things like this.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php

As far as installing MSSQL extensions, you will need to "change" your installation of PHP and enable the MSSQL extension.  This will automatically install the extension for you.  Then, just make sure your php.ini file has the extension enabled (there will be a [MSSQL] block).

Comment: I have added content from my php.ini file - does anything need changing in your eyes?

Comment: Check that you have a line that says: `extension=php_mssql.dll` and that is is uncommented.  Also, make sure that there a php_mssql.dll file located in the directory marked by the `extension_dir` portion of the ini file.

Comment: Ok it wasn't in there, so I added the line, then downloaded php_mssql.dll and popped it in the ext folder.

Comment: ok it wasn't in there so I added it in - then i downloaded php_mssql.dll and placed it in the ext folder - did an iisreset but no change - should I do something else? do I need to do something with ntwdblib.dll?

Comment: Check that your `extension=php_mssql.dll` is located under the Dynamic Extensions section of the ini file.  Seach for `Dynamic Extensions` and you will other dynamic extensions that have been loaded in listed there.  You may have to change your PHP installation (usually found in Control Panel -> Add/Remove Programs and clicking the change button for PHP).  Once in there, make sure the mssql extension is enabled.  You shouldn't need to do anything with the ntwdblib.dll.  After that, stop and start IIS.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Jeepers Creepers! Ok so I found the Dynamic Extension bit - there was nothing in there - so I added the line extension=php_mssql.dll to that section to. Normal extensions were at the very bottom of the file.

I've gone into PHP manager like the guy above said, it says the extension is enabled. I've stopped/started IIS but I still get:

Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mssql_connect() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\essentialibiza\php\objects\shared\db-connection.php on line 27

I find that in the error log - no idea why not in the browser!

Comment: The most likely reason it is not showing up in the browser is the error reporting you are using.  Try adding these lines to the very top of your PHP file `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Answer (score 0):

If you used an MSI to install PHP, the error messages probably live in `C:\Windows\Temp\php-errors.log`. I suspect your error message will be in their.

If you want to configure PHP on IIS, I suggest you install [PHP Manager for IIS](http://phpmanager.codeplex.com/). This will let you see what modules are installed, and add new ones, and exposes a GUI for all your PHP settings. In addition it will detect things that are wrong with your php.ini. It also has a "just open php.ini in notepad" link.

Comment: [18-Aug-2011 18:01:29] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mssql_connect() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\essentialibiza\php\objects\shared\db-connection.php on line 27

So I guess the guy is right about the extension not being installed. See below to see my progress with trying to install it. I must be getting close!

Comment: Ok you have some visibility now! If you install PHP Manager for IIS there is a "add/remove" list of available modules. That would simplify things a lot. I don't disagree with Kyle's troubleshooting steps. I'd do the same things on PHP for unix. However, PHP manager for IIS will edit the ini file for you, and give you better visual feedback. You can also save a copy of your current php.ini file and use a diff tool later to see how it "fixed" your config.

Comment: So what do I do if php_mssql.dll is enabled in PHP Manager? Can looking at phpmyinfo shed any light? I've also found the radio button to say this is a dev box and I want errors sent to the browser ;)

Super appreciate your help so far, I seem to be so close! Extension enabled but error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect()

Comment: Interesting post the output of phpinfo(INFO_MODULES) to a pastebin and post the link.

Comment: Added to original post - if it's unreadable I can always upload it as HTML. Thanks so much!

Comment: When I look at my full phpinfo(), the only mentions of mssql are in Congure Command:

"--without-mssql" "--without-pdo-mssql"