# PHP - How do I tell why mssql_connect() didn't work?

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm using PHP 5.2, and normally `mssql_connect`  works fine - but I'm trying to connect to a new MS SQL server, and it won't connect. I've probably got something wrong in the connection details or credentials, but I have no way of telling as I can't get an error message.

The `mssql_connect()` method returns *false*, and no connection is available.

`mssql_get_last_message()` returns nothing - so how do I tell why my connection failed?

Anyone got any ideas?

In MySQL I'd use `mysql_error` - but there doesn't seem to be an equivalent for ms_sql.

**[EDIT]**

This question is not a duplicate of "[MSSQL_CONNECT returns nothing - no error but no response either](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7107172/mssql-connect-returns-nothing-no-error-but-no-response-either)" - I'm using php 5.2, and the code works fine for other connection details. I need to figure out how to output what the connection error is - not what the problem is with connecting.

**[EDIT2]**

To clarify:

- the extension is enabled on the server
- the code works fine for existing connection details
- I am using new connection details and don't know if the hostname or password is wrong
- I know the code isn't connecting because I check to see if it's connected
- I want to find out the connection error - like you can with MySQL.

Sample code below:

```
    $db_connection = mssql_connect($host, $user, $pass);

    $db = mssql_select_db($dbname, $db_connection);
    if (!$db_connection) {
        echo "No connection";
        echo "connection failed because: " . ???????;
        die;
    }
```

What do I put in place of `???????` to get the connection error message?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MSSQL\_CONNECT returns nothing - no error but no response either](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7107172/mssql-connect-returns-nothing-no-error-but-no-response-either)

Comment: No - i'm asking how to get the connection error - not what is wrong with the connection. the code works for other connection parameters. Plus that's for php 5.3 - and there are compatibility issues with that version

Answer (score -1):

```
//Database Connection by PDO (MS SQL Server, PHP)
$serverName='localhost';
$database='TreeDB';
$uid='sa';
$pwd='sa*5234';

$dbo = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$serverName ; Database = $database;ConnectionPooling=0", $uid, $pwd);
//var_dump($dbo);

//Database Query
$sql = "SELECT  node.id, node.name, COUNT(parent.id) - 1 AS depth, node.lft, node.rgt 
FROM dbo.OrgTree AS node CROSS JOIN dbo.OrgTree AS parent
WHERE (node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt)
GROUP BY node.id, node.name, node.lft, node.rgt 
ORDER BY node.lft";

//Execute Query
$sql = $dbo->prepare($sql);
$sql->execute();

$qry = $sql->fetchAll();
foreach ($qry as $fetch) 
{
    $tree[] = $fetch;
}

//print_r($tree);
```

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with the question.

Answer (score -3):

See below

```
<?php
// Server in the this format: <computer>\<instance name> or 
// <server>,<port> when using a non default port number
$server = 'KALLESPC\SQLEXPRESS';

// Connect to MSSQL
$link = mssql_connect($server, 'sa', 'phpfi');

if (!$link) {
die('Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL');
}
?>
```

In this way you can display error if connection fails.

Ref: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php

Comment: Thanks - but that only tells me something failed - I already have that. I need to know *what* failed. The actual error returned by the attempt to connect - otherwise I don't know what I did wrong.

Comment: did you enabled the mssql extension in php.ini file?

Comment: Yes. Please read my question. The code works for other connections - I just need to use some new connection details. I don't know which bit of the connection is wrong because it doesn't tell me if the hostname is wrong or if the username is wrong - I need the connection error.

Comment: try this  if (!$query) { die('MSSQL error: ' . mssql_get_last_message());}

Comment: if it is returning nothing that should be problem with ur credentials

Comment: Thanks - I did (as mentioned in my question) - mssql_get_last_message() returns nothing

Comment: So it's definitely the credentials, and not the hostname?

Comment: Well, I've fixed the code - it was the hostname, so I think your theory is wrong. Thanks anyway. I still want to be able to display the error in future though

Comment: @Hippyjim: can you share with me, in your case, what's wrong with the hostname? I'm supporting an application with php 5.2 too.